# Python wordnet from nltk.corpus.Как получить определение каждого слова в нескольких предложениях с помощью wordnet?

Tags: python, nltk

Изучая wordnet, столкнулся с тем, что все примеры привязаны к работе с одним словом. А как получить определение каждого слова в нескольких предложениях с помощью wordnet?

Пытался как-то так адаптировать пример:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

words = []
synt = "Who doesn't love music? Whatever mood we have - bad or good, from time to time we turn on our favorite song. And it, in turn, either calms us, or on the contrary, makes us fall into melancholy. Life without music would be boring and dull. Just imagine a disco being in silence or holidays being without musicians. Absolutely all people of every type around the world are not indifferent to the music.Genres that are most popular are rock, rap, pop, techno, chanson, hip-hop and others. Many people believe that music is first and foremost an instrument of the soul. For example, I like Spanish folk songs. Listening to foreign songs I improve my knowledge of English. This is a great way to mix business with pleasure."


words = word_tokenize(synt)

for w in words:
word = wordnet.synsets('{w}')[0]
print("Synset name : ", word.name())
# Defining the word
print("\nSynset meaning : ", word.definition())
# list of phrases that use the word in context
print("\nSynset example : ", word.examples())
```

Но не вышло:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/projects/WordNet/test.py", line 10, in <module>
    word = wordnet.synsets('{w}')[0]
IndexError: list index out of range

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы получили ошибку `list index out of range` поскольку метод `wordnet.synsets('{w}')` вернул результат нулевой длины. Вы не проверив этого пытаетесь обратится к элементу `[0]`, которого нет. Добавьте проверку результата, прежде чем пытаться его выводить.

К примеру, следующим образом

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet

synt = "Who doesn't love music? Whatever mood we have - bad or good, from time to time we turn on our favorite song. And it, in turn, either calms us, or on the contrary, makes us fall into melancholy. Life without music would be boring and dull. Just imagine a disco being in silence or holidays being without musicians. Absolutely all people of every type around the world are not indifferent to the music.Genres that are most popular are rock, rap, pop, techno, chanson, hip-hop and others. Many people believe that music is first and foremost an instrument of the soul. For example, I like Spanish folk songs. Listening to foreign songs I improve my knowledge of English. This is a great way to mix business with pleasure."
words = synt.split(' ')

for word in words:
    result = wordnet.synsets(word)
    if not result:
        print('No found: ', word)
        continue

    for item in result:
        print("Synset name: ", item.name())
        print("Synset meaning: ", item.definition())
        print("Synset example: ", item.examples())
```